# How does boost::beast::bind_front_handler works?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-beast

I am trying `boost::beast` examples, I came across to this piece of code.

```
    void on_write(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t byte_transferred) {
        if (ec) return fail(ec, "write");

        http::async_read(m_tcp_stream, m_buffer, m_response, beast::bind_front_handler(
            &Session::on_read, shared_from_this()));
    }

    void on_read(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
        if (ec) return fail(ec, "read");
        //std::cout << m_response << std::endl;
        write_on_file(m_response);
        m_tcp_stream.socket().shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec);
        if (ec && ec != beast::errc::not_connected) return fail(ec, "showdown");
    }
```

Particularly `http::async_read(m_tcp_stream, m_buffer, m_response, beast::bind_front_handler(&Session::on_read, shared_from_this()));` this line. I am not able to understand its code. How does it work. As far as I get from the code, that It returns `bind_front_wrapper` which constructs a `Handler` and `tuple of args` within itself. But I did not understand how does it manage to get the arguments of the passed `Handler` in `bind_front_handler` even though we are not passing, we are just passing `shared_ptr`. In this case `async_read` is calling `on_read` method. But we are not passing any parameters, but still it get called, I wonder how?

Answer (score 4):

You use asynchronous operations, so your job is to define callbacks which are called
by Beast core code when operations are completed. When an operation started by `async_read` is ready,
handler passed to `async_read` is called with two arguments: error code + number of transferred bytes.
You decided to wrap `on_read` into callback by `bind_front_handler`. `bind_front_handler` generates a functor object
whose implementation in pseudocode may look like:

```
class Handler {
    void (Session::*onRead)(...); // pointer to on_read function member of Session
    Session* session;  // pointer to session, get by shared_from_this

    Handler(/* pointer to on_read, pointer to session */) {}

    template<class ... Args>
    void operator() (Args... args) {
        ((*session).*onRead)(args...);
    }        
}
```

when read operation is ready, function `operator()` of above handler is called with two arguments pack: error code
and number of read bytes.

Since c++20 there is `std::bind_front`,
you may visit [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front) to get more details how it could be implemented in Beast library.

Comment: [tag:boost] can be a pretty thankless pit :) Thanks for writing  awesome answers like these

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful answer. But, as a novice, I got confused at the last sentence. What is the relationship between `beast::bind_front_handler` and `std::bind_front`?